# the name properties does not exist in the current context?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm getting an error that says the name properties does not exist in the current context? The rest of the code seems fine, apart from this error, I'm aware there are similar questions however I'm struggling to apply the solutions in my own problem.

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.ServiceModel;
    using System.ServiceModel.Web;
    using System.Text;
namespace transportservices
public class Service1 : transport

     {
                public int insertData(string shop, string car, string train)
                {


                    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.SQL_String))
```

Comment: your entire code doesn't contain `name` !

Comment: what do you mean, aplogies

Comment: is something missing after string train, ? There's a comma, but nothing following it.

Comment: No sorry i potted that after copying the code over, removing the comma did takeaway the properties error

Comment: where is `name` ?? which line gives the exception ?

Comment: I think your class should be inside namespace {}

Comment: the last line "using (sql conn." specifically "properties" is underlined red with the error mentioned

Comment: the code is copied from a working example but changed for my database so transport instead of sweets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have SQL_String property on your project. To add

1. Right click your project
2. Click on Properties
3. Go to Resources tab
4. Select Resource type string
5. In the grid Add SQL_String as Name of your resource name and provide value.

Your project namespace and class consuming that resource should have same namespace else you have to import that namespace in class.

Comment: Thanks I will have a go when i get the chance I'll select yours as answer if it works..

Comment: Sorry, i'm not sure what to put in the value column [edit i  found what i need please ignore]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding a new dummy setting as follow:
[image: Settings- dummy setting]

then clicking the Save button. All errors saying "the name 'properties' does not exist in the current context" disappeared.